# react - not able to setValue for input box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-otp-input

I am making 2 otp input in my application.

In `Input.tsx`, I am using `react-otp-input` for the otp functionality
if

```
    <OtpInput
      value={"abcde"}
      ...
      numInputs={5}
    />
```

The UI of `react-otp-input` will be

[image]

Now the problem is, when I try to change the value of otp, it throws error

```
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')
```

How can I fix it?

Input.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import OtpInput from "react-otp-input";

type InputPropType = {
  value: string;
  setValue: (event: string) => void;
};

function Input(props: InputPropType): JSX.Element {
  const { value, setValue } = props;
  return (
    <OtpInput
      value={value}
      onChange={(e: string) => {
        setValue(e);
      }}
      numInputs={5}
    />
  );
}

export default Input;
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Input from "./Input";

export default function App() {
  type InputValueType = {
    id: number;
    value: string;
  };
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState<Array<InputValueType>>([
    { id: 0, value: "" },
    { id: 1, value: "" }
  ]);

  const InputGroup = () => {
    let numOfInputs: number = 2;
    var rows: Array<any> = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfInputs; i++) {
      let inputValue: InputValueType = inputValues[i];
      rows.push(
        <Input
          key={inputValue.id}
          value={inputValue.value}
          setValue={(event: string) => {
            let inputValuesTemp = inputValues;
            inputValuesTemp[i]["value"] = event;
            setInputValues(inputValuesTemp);
          }}
        />
      );
    }
    return <>{rows}</>;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <InputGroup />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-s38ck9?file=/src/App.tsx:0-918

Comment: What file and line number did the error say it was on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things to be corrected,

1. There is an issue with closures in your for-loop since you have used `var` instead of `let`. All the `i` variables refer to the same for-loop closure in the for-loop, which means `i` is `2` at the end of the iteration.
   All the `inputValuesTemp[i]` are now resolved to `inputValuesTemp[2]` which is definitely `undefined`.

Replace `var` with `let` to create closures for each iteration of the loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < numOfInputs; i++) {...}
```

2. And, you also need o get a copy of the values array for react to do a rerender (to inform that the array has changed).

```
let inputValuesTemp = [...inputValues];
```

3. Your `InputGroup` component was within the `App` component, which caused you to lose focus for each keystroke. To fix the focus issue, move the `InputGroup` out of the `App` and keep it as a separate component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Input from "./Input";

type InputValueType = {
  id: number;
  value: string;
};

const InputGroup = () => {
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState<Array<InputValueType>>([
    { id: 0, value: "" },
    { id: 1, value: "" }
  ]);

  let numOfInputs: number = 2;
  var rows: Array<any> = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numOfInputs; i++) {
    let inputValue: InputValueType = inputValues[i];
    rows.push(
      <Input
        key={inputValue.id}
        value={inputValue.value}
        setValue={(event: string) => {
          let inputValuesTemp = [...inputValues];
          inputValuesTemp[i]["value"] = event;
          setInputValues(inputValuesTemp);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
  return <>{rows}</>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <InputGroup />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Typescript (forked)]

Comment: @CCCC, check this out !!

Comment: it's a great solution! but after your changes I can't move the focus of input after typing a character. How to fix it?

Comment: @CCC, You need to create a separate new component for `InputGroup` without keeping it inside another component top-level. I have updated the code sandbox.